# Phonegap Fade In/Out choppy but using hardware acceleration sometime crashes Android

Tags: cordova, fadein, phonegap-build

Problem on how to make smooth Fadein/out or any related type CSS/Javascript Animation on Phonegap App.

I am working on an example that i have multiple Div in a page, when button is clicked, part fadeout and then another part fadein etc.

Everything is working great when i test it on browser and simulator. But when i package it into an App, the Fadein/Fade out becomes very Choppy. I had the same problem before with Idangerous Swiper when i do dynamic height. I forced hardware acceleration on it. But sometimes crashes the app.

I am wondering if i force it by using transform3d does that only apply to that specific div? Or would hardware acceleration be forced on the whole time?

And if there are any other way to make a smooth fadein/out animation on a phonegap app?

Thanks

Edit:
I just tried to test the part that supposed to fadein/out alone with nothing else, they are still choppy.

Then i tried to use transform3d(0,0,0) to force hardware acceleration and it is still choppy.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things, there is nothing much i couldnt find out except using Velocity.js 
http://julian.com/research/velocity/

It helps, its good enough. But not sure if it is a good idea to keep adding plugins, as it might cause more vulnerability to the structure. But will do for now.